# Saber si un numero es Par o impar usando recursividad indirecta

Tags: java

Es posible resolver un ejercicio donde se pide saber si un numero es par o impar usando recursividad indirecta?

La consigna es: Hacer un Algoritmo recursivo que permita saber si un numero es impar utilizando recursividad indirecta

Lo que yo realice es lo siguiente pero no sé si está bien el concepto:

```
public class EjercicioTrece {

public static void main(String[]args){

    testPositivo(5);
    testPositivo(-1);
    testPositivo(100);
    testPositivo(-1000);

}


public static void testPositivo(int num1){
    System.out.println(esPositivo(num1));
}


public static boolean esPositivo(int num){

    if(num < 0){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hola Maxi. Has de explicar mejor tu pregunta, Además, aqui se resuelven preguntas trabajadas previamente por lo que has de mostrarnos tus intentos y por qué no te funcionaron. Mira [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Hola tenias razón! ahí reformule la duda y agregue el código que había hecho

Comment: @MaxiHernandez, el código que has subido no tiene nada que ver con el ejercicio que propones, debemos deducir que no sabes como empezar o te has equivocado de código?

Comment: El código aportado no parece estar relacionado con la pregunta ¿Conoces el concepto `recursividad indirecta`?

Comment: Para poder resolver esto, hay que tener claro que es la recursividad indirecta.

La recursividad indirecta significa que una función llama a una segunda función y esa segunda a la primera, así sucesivamente hasta que llegas a un resultado. Te recomiendo que mires esta presentación hasta el final, te valdrá para lo que quieres. https://prezi.com/fpoihfevo3bw/que-es-la-recursividad/

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano estoy aprendiendo el concepto de recursividad y tenia la consigna que pase y no sabia como comenzar el ejercicio como se aplicaba la recursividad.

Answer (score 4):

Es un ejemplo clásico para ver cómo funciona la **recursividad indirecta**. La dificultad reside principalmente en descubrir cómo aplicar la recursividad más que en su programación.

```
public static boolean impar (int num){
    if (num == 0) 
        return false;
    else
        return par(num-1);
}

public static boolean par (int num) {
    if (num == 0) 
        return true;
    else
        return impar(num-1);
}
```

De esta manera si por ejemplo llamamos al método `impar(3)` el programa haría `par(2) -> impar(1) -> par(0) -> true` afirmando como sabemos que *tres es impar*. Si hacemos por el contrario `par(3)` hará `impar(2) -> par(1) -> impar(0) -> false`, es lioso pero no difícil.

La mejor forma de aprender es que mires unos cuantos ejemplos, entiendas su funcionamiento (personalmente haciendo una traza a mano es como mejor me resulta) y luego pruebes a hacer algún ejercicio.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda ;)

Comment: gracias por el aporte lo voy a analizar, pero asi a simple vista es mas simple de lo que habia pensado. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para saber si un numero es par o impar no necesitas recursividad, esta sentencia diria si un numero es par o impar:

```
int num=0;

if(num%2==0){
System.out.println("El numero es par");
}else
System.out.println("El numero es impar");
```

Es decir, si un numero es divisible entre 2 sera par, si no lo es divisible entre 2 es impar. la recursividad se utiliza como sentencia iterativa , se asemejaria a un bucle , y nocesitas algo asi para determinar si un numero es par o impar

Comment: Hola Alex, gracias por tu respuesta. Procura esperar a que el autor mejore la pregunta para aclarar lo mejor posible su problema. Un saludo

Comment: De acuerdo @lois6b, tienes razon

Comment: No creo que el usuario quiera saber si un valor es par o impar. Deja claro que necesita hacerlo mediante recursividad indirecta.